# How to do sum and remove duplicate using group by in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, group-by, xslt-1.0

i have a requirement to group all input element and perform some action.

If i get input as -

```
 <ns1:users>
              <ns1:user>
                <ns1:name>A</ns1:name>
                 <ns1:ProductIdentifier>1234</ns1:ProductIdentifier>
                 <ns1:Quantity>100</ns1:Quantity>
              </ns1:user>
              <ns1:user>
         <ns1:name>B</ns1:name>
                 <ns1:ProductIdentifier>1234</ns1:ProductIdentifier>
                 <ns1:Quantity>200</ns1:Quantity>
              </ns1:user>
    <ns1:user>
         <ns1:name>C</ns1:name>
                 <ns1:ProductIdentifier>12345</ns1:ProductIdentifier>
                 <ns1:Quantity>300</ns1:Quantity>
              </ns1:user>
           </ns1:users>
```

i have to group by element ProductIdentifier and if there are 2 or more than 2 same ProductIdentifier then i have to send only 1st copy of Productidentifier and quantity must be sum of all same product identifier.

Output -

```
<ns1:users>
          <ns1:user>
            <ns1:name>A</ns1:name>
             <ns1:ProductIdentifier>1234</ns1:ProductIdentifier>
             <ns1:Quantity>300</ns1:Quantity>
          </ns1:user>
          <ns1:user>

<ns1:user>
     <ns1:name>C</ns1:name>
             <ns1:ProductIdentifier>12345</ns1:ProductIdentifier>
             <ns1:Quantity>300</ns1:Quantity>
          </ns1:user>
       </ns1:users>
```

My XSLT -

```
 <xsl:key match="user" name="ProductIdentifier" use="ProductIdentifier"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">

       <xsl:for-each select="users/user[generate-id()=generate-id(key('ProductIdentifier',ProductIdentifier)[1])]">

                <ns1:user>

                <ns1:name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>

                  </ns1:name>

                  <ns1:ProductIdentifier>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ProductIdentifier"/>

                  </ns1:ProductIdentifier>
                   <ns1:Quantity>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('ProductIdentifier',ProductIdentifier)">

                   <xsl:value-of select="sum(Quantity)"/>


                   </xsl:for-each>
                  </ns1:Quantity>

                </ns1:user>

              </xsl:for-each>
            </ns1:users>
```

Output is coming like this -

```
<ns1:users>
      <ns1:user>
      <ns1:name>A</ns1:name>
         <ns1:ProductIdentifier>1078859</ns1:ProductIdentifier>
         <ns1:Quantity>100200</ns1:Quantity>
      </ns1:LeftOnBoardPart>
      <ns1:LeftOnBoardPart>
      <ns1:name>C</ns1:name>
         <ns1:ProductIdentifier>C</ns1:ProductIdentifier>
         <ns1:Quantity>300</ns1:Quantity>
      </ns1:LeftOnBoardPart>
   </ns1:LeftOnBoardParts>
```

How to sum 100 + 200 = 300?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow is not a "write my code for me" site.

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Does your input have prefixed elements like `<ns1:users>`? If yes, please add the missing namespace declarations. Your XSLT seems to work with another input, where the elements have no prefix, e.g. `<users>`.

Answer (score 0):

For the quantity, do:

```
<ns1:Quantity>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('ProductIdentifier', ProductIdentifier)/Quantity)"/>
</ns1:Quantity>
```